# Manipulating rows of csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, vbscript

Ok so I have a csv file and I need to grab informtaion from each row and manipulate it to generate a distance.

So this is the code written in VBscript

```
' this is just the set up part - don't worry about it
Set thepts = document.componentset("points").OwnedTable
Set theComments = document.ComponentSet("Comments")

' this is all the code you need
for each rec1 in thepts.recordset
 for each rec2 in thepts.recordset
 thedist = ((rec1.Data("X (I)") - rec2.Data("X (I)"))^2 - (rec1.Data("Y     (I)") - rec2.Data("Y (I)"))^2)
 theComments.AddText rec1.Data("OBJECTID")&","&rec2.Data("OBJECTID")&","&thedist &vbcrlf 
 next
 next
 End Sub
```

Sorry if the above code looks bad I had it saved in notepad but here is what my current python code looks like

```
import csv
import math

f = open('citydata.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
  for row in csv_f:
    x1 = row[2]
    x2 = row[3]
    x1 = float(x1)
    x2 = float(x2)
    for row in csv_f:
        y1 = row[2]
        y2 = row[3]
        y1 = float(y1)
        y2 = float(y2)
answer = (x1-(math.pow(x2,2)))-(y1-(math.pow(y2,2)))
print(answer)
```

So I am takeing (x1-x2^2) - (y1-y2*2)

and the csv file is setup like

first row= ID   IDSP2010    x   y   long    lat ORIG_FID

Then rest of rows will be information

The only information that matters is the numbers under the x and y

So I can think of how to do it in c++ with an array but I cant wrap my head around it in python. I have never really worked with python before so please take it easy and I wrote a lot just to make sure you understood everything I was doing please ask any questions if you are confused cause you know I am

Comment: I have no idea what your actual question is. What part doesn't work? Please take some time to read [help] and [mcve].

Comment: if you can do it with a c++ array, why can't you do it with a python array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're going for, but maybe this will work. You're currently re-using the variable name 'row', and the indentation is all wacky. Also, you shouldn't be including the first row (the headers) in your loops.

```
import csv
import math

f = open('citydata.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
content = [row for row in csv_f]

for row in content[1:]:
    x1 = float(row[2])
    x2 = float(row[3])
    for rowOther in content[1:]:
        y1 = float(rowOther[2])
        y2 = float(rowOther[3])

        answer = (x1-(math.pow(x2,2))) - (y1-(math.pow(y2,2)))

        print(answer)
```

EDIT:

I just realized that I think you had your x's and y's swapped in a couple places. Try this instead:

```
import csv
import math

f = open('citydata.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
content = [row for row in csv_f]

for row in content[1:]:
    x1 = float(row[2])
    y1 = float(row[3])
    for rowOther in content[1:]:
        x2 = float(rowOther[2])
        y2 = float(rowOther[3])

        answer = (x1-(math.pow(x2,2))) - (y1-(math.pow(y2,2)))

        print(answer)
```

Comment: Yes, the [1:] means that it starts on the second row (index 1). rowOther is used since you're iterating over the rows within an iteration of the rows, so 'row' and 'rowOther' refer to different rows from one another (well, most of the time). If you used 'row' there, it wouldn't necessarily effect the result in this case (since you've already assigned the row contents to new, immutable variables), but it's a bad precedent.

Comment: Ok cool thank you for clearing that up. I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

`csv_f` is a file (wrapped in a csv reader). The inner loop is going to read it all. Once it reaches the end you can't read anymore, so the other loops are going to stop there.

What you want is first to copy everything out of the file into memory (`data = [x for x in csv_f]`) and then apply the same algorithm (on `data`).

Also in python indentation matters so your formula is only computed once at the end. Indentation defines the code block for `for` loops or `if` statements. From your VB script looks like you want it computed for all pairs of lines. So add tabs/spaces to allign it correctly (probably print as well).

Probably you also want to remove the outer most loop since that will cause  the program to repeat everything for every line in the file.